# Django admin list_display weirdly slow with foreign keys

Tags: python, performance, django-admin, foreign-keys

Django 1.2.5
Python: 2.5.5

My admin list of a sports model has just gone really slow (5 minutes for 400 records). It was returning in a second or so until we got 400 games, 50 odd teams and 2 sports.

I have fixed it in an awful way so I'd like to see if anyone has seen this before. My app looks like this:

```
models:

Sport( models.Model )
    name

Venue( models.Model )
    name

Team( models.Model )
    name

Fixture( models.Model )
    date
    sport = models.ForeignKey(Sport)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue)

TeamFixture( Fixture )
    team1 = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="Team 1")
    team2 = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="Team 2")


admin:

TeamFixture_ModelAdmin (ModelAdmin)
    list_display = ('date','sport','venue','team1','team2',)
```

If I remove any foreign keys from list_display then it's quick. As soon as I add any foreign key then slow.

I fixed it by using non foreign keys but calculating them in the model init so this works:

```
models:

TeamFixture( Fixture )
    team1 = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="Team 1")
    team2 = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="Team 2")
    sport_name = ""
    venue_name = ""
    team1_name = ""
    team2_name = ""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TeamFixture, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.sport_name = self.sport.name
        self.venue_name = self.venue.name
        self.team1_name = self.team1.name
        self.team2_name = self.team2.name

admin:

TeamFixture_ModelAdmin (ModelAdmin)
    list_display = ('date','sport_name','venue_name','team1_name','team2_name',)
```

Administration for all other models are fine with several thousand records at the moment and all views in the actual site is functioning fine.

Answer (score 4):

It's driving me crazy. list_select_related is set to True, however adding a foreign key to User in the list_display generates one query per row in the admin, which makes the listing slow. Select_related is True, so the Django admin shouldn't call this query on each row.
What is going on ?

Comment: Steve K did you ever get this fixed?  I am in _exactly_ the same bind and am going mad...

Comment: Yes, I fixed it about 2 years ago. Your `ModelAdmin` needs to override `get_queryset` (see the docs) to add a `select_related()` statement. You can also play with the `only` and `defer` fields, anything you want.

Comment: Thankyou @steve-k thanks to you I might get to spend some time with my family this xmas.

Comment: Best to create a custom Manager on your models to make sure that select_related is always used instead of doing select_related for every query

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I would look for, are the database calls. If you shouldn't have done that already, install [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar). That awesome tool lets you inspect all sql queries done for the current request. I assume there are lots of them. If you look at them, you will know where to look for the problem.

One problem I myself have run into: When the `__unicode__` method of a model uses a foreign key, that leads to one database hit per instance. I know of two ways to overcome this problem:

- use [`select_related`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related), which usually is your best bet.
- make your `__unicode__` return a static string and override the `save` method to update this string accordingly.

Comment: Also - where you can, in your unicode functions,  be aware of calling foreign key unicode functions. These cause further subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old problem with django admin and foreign keys. What happens here is that whenever you try to load an object it tries to get all the objects of that foreign key. So lets say you are trying to load a fixture with a some teams (say the number of teams is about 100), its going to keep on including all the 100 teams in one go. You can try to optimize them by using something called as `raw_fields`. What this would do is instead of having to calling everything at once, it will limit the number of calls and make sure that the call is only made when an event is triggered (i.e. when you are selecting a team).
If that seems a bit like a UI mess you can try using this class:

```
"""
For Raw_id_field to optimize django performance for many to many fields
"""
class RawIdWidget(ManyToManyRawIdWidget):
    def label_for_value(self, value):
        values = value.split(',')
        str_values = []
        key = self.rel.get_related_field().name
        for v in values:
            try:
                obj = self.rel.to._default_manager.using(self.db).get(**{key: v})
                x = smart_unicode(obj)
                change_url = reverse(
                    "admin:%s_%s_change" % (obj._meta.app_label, obj._meta.object_name.lower()),
                    args=(obj.pk,)
                )
                str_values += ['<strong><a href="%s">%s</a></strong>' % (change_url, escape(x))]
            except self.rel.to.DoesNotExist:
                str_values += [u'No input or index in the db']
        return u', '.join(str_values)

class ImproveRawId(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ('created_by', 'updated_by')
    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name in self.raw_id_fields:
            kwargs.pop("request", None)
            type = db_field.rel.__class__.__name__
            kwargs['widget'] = RawIdWidget(db_field.rel, site)
            return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
        return super(ImproveRawId, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
```

Just make sure that you inherit the class properly. I am guessing something like `TeamFixture_ModelAdmin (ImproveRawIdFieldsForm)`. This will most likely give you a pretty cool performance boost in your django admin.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by setting `list_select_related` to the list of related model fields instead of just `True`