# A lots of foreign keys - Django Admin

Tags: sql, django, query-optimization, admin, models

Have a SQL problem, adding this model all works correctly, the problem is in ADMIN.

When I add the data just few to each table, by clicking on `TYPE` & `PAGE` in `ADMIN` the page is loading so slow, installed `debug_toolbar` and SQL took 17 seconds for the `TYPE`. When I tried the `PAGE` it gave me timeout, my question is what is wrong with my model? Is it constructed bad?

My goal is this lets say example:

http://www.example.com/audi/4doors/s4/sport/red/audi-url

Basically all 6 urls are dynamic that I would specify in the each table and would be in the `PAGE` as dropdowns also in others. What is the optimal way to do that or optimize the model?

Here is a screenshot of TYPE page loading:

screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/2931040E0t35

Please help thanks

```
from django.db import models

class Client(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Category(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, to_field='title')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Subcategory(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, to_field='title')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, to_field='title')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Project(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, to_field='title')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, to_field='title')
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, to_field='title')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Type(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, to_field='title')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, to_field='title')
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, to_field='title')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, to_field='title')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Page(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, to_field='title')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, to_field='title')
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, to_field='title')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, to_field='title')
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, to_field='title')
    pageurl = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Also just found out when I remove Foreign Keys from `admin.py` from `list_display`, it works blazing fast:

```
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title',)
    admin.site.register(Client, ClientAdmin)

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('client', 'title',)
    admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)

class SubcategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('client', 'category', 'title', )
    admin.site.register(Subcategory, SubcategoryAdmin)

class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('client', 'category', 'subcategory', 'title', )
    admin.site.register(Project, ProjectAdmin)

class TypeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('client', 'title', )
    admin.site.register(Type, TypeAdmin)

class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('client', )
    admin.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)
```

**FOREIGN KEYS cannot be in list_display? How to optimize them?**

Update:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, db_index=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Category(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Subcategory(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Project(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Type(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Page(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type)
    pageurl = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

UPDATE 2

```
from django.db import models


class Client(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Category(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Subcategory(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Project(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Type(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Page(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type)
    pageurl = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

UPDATE 3 - ADMIN.PY

```
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('title',)

admin.site.register(Client, ClientAdmin)

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('client', 'title',)

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)

class SubcategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('client', 'category', 'title', )

admin.site.register(Subcategory, SubcategoryAdmin)

class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

        list_display = ('client', 'category', 'subcategory', 'title', )

admin.site.register(Project, ProjectAdmin)

class TypeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('client', 'category', 'subcategory', 'project', 'title', )

admin.site.register(Type, TypeAdmin)

class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

   list_display = ('client', 'category', 'subcategory', 'project', 'type', 'pageurl', )

admin.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)
```

Comment: How many records do you have in each table?

Comment: auto_client = 3 rows, auto_category = 2 rows, auto_subcategory = 2 rows, auto_project = 5 rows, auto_type = 2 rows, auto_page = 0 - because cliking on auto_page it times out because of SQL query. Basically togehter like 14 records thats nothing :), here is also mysql query in PHPmyadmin:

http://cl.ly/image/2S320h3d0P0J

17 seconds, and also screenshot from debug_toolbar: http://cl.ly/image/081h1l3X1D28

Comment: FOREIGN KEYS cannot be in list_display? How to optimize them?

Comment: Why don't you use primary keys for relations? You are making a ton of joins and the relations are performed to fields that are not primary keys. Think about the database schema, this is not a standard approach. Could you explain why you have taken this approach?

Comment: Can you make an example on above solution how should I make it properly that would help me a lot thanks, later on I want to use django-smart-select for dropdowns in admin that it can filter dynamicly if I select clent it will refresh others and it worked but that long SQL query took place I thought it was the django-smart-select plugin so I removed it and rewrite it to foreign keys but if u can show me proper layout would be great :)

Comment: For example this: `client = models.ForeignKey(Client, to_field='title')` is rather not necessary complexity, which could be replaced by this: `client = models.ForeignKey(Client)` or, if you need to name reverse relation: `client = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name='categories')`. You are just making foreign keys to something else than primary keys seemingly without reason. If you need to use `title` fields as primary keys, just make them primary keys (`primary_key=True` in field kwargs). However this may be not the only issue. Tell us if the issue was fixed.

Comment: Updated the question above just like you said, still 60 seconds for the query, the problem is in admin.py when I use Foreign Keys in  list_display = ('client', 'category', 'subcategory', 'project', 'title', ), when I remove them and leave only non-foreign keys it works super fast.

Comment: Found this but not sure in django docs - Set list_select_related to tell Django to use select_related() in retrieving the list of objects on the admin change list page. This can save you a bunch of database queries.
Note that Django will use select_related(), regardless of this setting if one of the list_display fields is a ForeignKey.

Comment: I am seeing this person having the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181233/django-admin-list-display-weirdly-slow-with-foreign-keys

Comment: And what is the `__unicode__()` method for `Page` model?

Comment: Havent added __unicode__() to that model, anyway if I click the TYPES that takes 60 seconds to load: http://cl.ly/image/193Z000b2J2T, not even talking about PAGE model which times out

Comment: Did a mysql PROFILING: Results:

Query:

http://cl.ly/image/0311392u0Z0S

CPU Profile:

http://cl.ly/image/2D210h0f1L06

Comment: And what about the query when you do not use foreign keys? I see at least 15 joins in this query...

Comment: when I remove from admin list_display = ('client', 'category', 'subcategory', 'project', 'title', ) FKs to list_display = ( 'title', ), SQL is SELECT `auto_type`.`id`, `auto_type`.`client_id`, `auto_type`.`category_id`, `auto_type`.`subcategory_id`, `auto_type`.`project_id`, `auto_type`.`title` FROM `auto_type` ORDER BY `auto_type`.`id` DESC - 1.97ms - http://cl.ly/image/0h3D292d2I0u

Comment: I am not sure if I am losing the track of your changes, but have you changed every `title` field to be `primary_key`?

Comment: YES, http://cl.ly/image/1R1p1D1i1F43

Comment: Then please update your answer with: 1) current code, 2) current results (performance), 3) current database structure (including indexes). There are multiple possibilities, so tell us also what version of Django you are using, what database backend you are using, and let us know about anything unusual (like extensive debugging, or something like the foreign keys you were using in the previous versin).

Comment: Updated Question with models.py: Added data like around 20 records together in all tables so each has like 2 or 3.

This model is faster for sure but still for 20 records very slow:

1. TYPE TABLE - http://cl.ly/image/3J1R2o1l1b2a

2. PAGE TABLE - http://cl.ly/image/0F0621002O2p

Did Also MySQL Profiling:

1. PAGE TABLE - CPU QUERY - http://cl.ly/image/0Z2e113J2t10

I am using Django 1.4.1

Comment: I will try to help you as much as I can, but this definitely looks like the issue with too many joins. Also is the code from the question exactly the one you are using? Is `admin.site.register` indented the same way `list_display` is?

Comment: Also did Update 3 with admin.py thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of that you can use [raw_id_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) option of django admin.

```
admin.site.register(Client)

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    raw_id_fields = ('client',)

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)

class SubcategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    raw_id_fields = ('client', 'category')

admin.site.register(Subcategory, SubcategoryAdmin)

class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    raw_id_fields = ('client', 'category', 'subcategory')

admin.site.register(Project, ProjectAdmin)

class TypeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    raw_id_fields = ('client', 'category', 'subcategory', 'project')

admin.site.register(Type, TypeAdmin)

class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    raw_id_fields = ('client', 'category', 'subcategory', 'project', 'type')

admin.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)
```

[image: this is the old one]
[image: this is new sql query]

Comment: wow, no idea how "raw_id_fields" work can you explain if possible? It is loading fast, how can I achieve for example to include in the list_display "title" which is in the model, but cant put it in the "raw_id_fields" cause thats used for foreign keys and many-to-many...thanks will add data and test it out

Comment: you use foreign keys and in the admin page when you want to click the page admin, django tries to get and join related all object of it. you can take a look to django documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, I am not sure if this is 100% relevant (since I use FKs in list_display *and* list_editable). I get speed up using the trick described here:
http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2012/01/19/tweaks-for-making-django-admin-faster/

It seems that the choices are evaluated for every row (esp when using list_editable for the FK), so using formfield_for_dbfield you can cache the choices as suggested in the link. This saves going to the db for rendering every single dropdown/select box for foreign_keys.

You can see the queries that are being executed on the view if you turn on the mysql general log (if you are using MySQL).